# convert url with .svg extension to image in cell - google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have column B which contains a url in each cell. I have column C that my intention is to be the url of the cell in column B converted into an image.

The urls with extension .png/.jpg converts them to images without problem.

The urls with the .svg extension cannot be converted into images.

And this is really a problem, because the urls are automatically synchronized from another platform to Google Sheets and they are practically all .svg extension.

The strangest thing is that with the formula "=IMAGE(urlCell)" the urls with .svg extension are converted into images without problem.

Also, I am getting the error "Exception: The parameters (Blob,String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.insertImage."

So what am I doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
function imagenIcono4() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(' Todos los eventos');
  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  
  var rango = sheet.getRange(2, 2, lastRow -1, 2);
  var values = rango.getValues();

  values.forEach((fila)=> {

    // Pon la imagen en todas las celdas donde la url no sea con extensión ".svg"
    if ( !fila[0].toString().includes(".svg")) { 

      fila[1] = SpreadsheetApp.newCellImage().setSourceUrl(fila[0]).toBuilder().build();

    } else {

      var url = fila[0];
      Logger.log(url);

      const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
      sheet.insertImage(blob, fila[1]);

    }
  }) 

  rango.setValues(values);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that unfortunately in the current stage, the SVG image data cannot be used for `sheet.insertImage` and `SpreadsheetApp.newCellImage().setSourceUrl`. By the way, the arguments of [`insertImage` are `blobSource, column, row`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=ja#insertimageblobsource,-column,-row) and [`blobSource, column, row, offsetX, offsetY`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=ja#insertimageblobsource,-column,-row,-offsetx,-offsety). If you want to use this, please be careful about this.

In your situation, I thought that [this method (Author: me)](https://tanaikech.github.io/2020/07/20/converting-svg-format-to-png-format-using-google-apps-script/) might be able to be used.

When this is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

In this case, Drive API is used. So, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

#### From:

```js
values.forEach((fila)=> {

  // Pon la imagen en todas las celdas donde la url no sea con extensión ".svg"
  if ( !fila[0].toString().includes(".svg")) { 

    fila[1] = SpreadsheetApp.newCellImage().setSourceUrl(fila[0]).toBuilder().build();

  } else {

    var url = fila[0];
    Logger.log(url);

    const blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
    sheet.insertImage(blob, fila[1]);

  }
})
```

#### To:

```js
values.forEach((fila) => {
  if (!fila[0].toString().includes(".svg")) {
    fila[1] = SpreadsheetApp.newCellImage().setSourceUrl(fila[0]).toBuilder().build();
  } else {
    Logger.log(fila[0]);
    var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(fila[0]).getBlob();
    var id = DriveApp.createFile(blob.setName("temp")).getId();
    Utilities.sleep(2000);
    var { thumbnailLink } = Drive.Files.get(id);
    fila[1] = SpreadsheetApp.newCellImage().setSourceUrl(thumbnailLink.replace("=s220", "=s1000")).toBuilder().build();
    DriveApp.getFileById(id).setTrashed(true);
  }
});
```

Comment: @Tainake I have followed your steps and tested your script and it works fine, however for only 8 rows it takes almost 20 seconds to run the entire function. I don't want to imagine with 1000 rows or more...

Comment: @Tainake Is there a way to ignore cells that already contain an image at the beginning of the function? In this way, you would avoid having to go through all the cells of the column each time and you would only have to go through the cells that do not contain an image.

Comment: @Nerea Thank you for replying. From `I have followed your steps and tested your script and it works fine`, I understood that your question was resolved. About `however for only 8 rows it takes almost 20 seconds to run the entire function. I don't want to imagine with 1000 rows or more...`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your question, I couldn't find it. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Nerea About `Is there a way to ignore cells that already contain an image at the beginning of the function? In this way, you would avoid having to go through all the cells of the column each time and you would only have to go through the cells that do not contain an image.`, I think that this is a new question. But, I would like to support you.

Comment: @ Tainake Thank you for your support. I have marked your answer as accept. And I have created another new post for the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75395305/ignore-cells-that-already-contain-an-image-google-apps-script